# Select specific values from an array within an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0, powercli

I am querying my storage array to gather properties for initiators. Here is the code:

```
$global:Xtrem_HBA_list = @()
$global:Xtrem_HBA_list += Get-XtremInitiators -Properties name,port-address,ig-id
$Write-Host $global:Xtrem_HBA_list
```

This returns

```
name                 port-address             ig-id
----                 ------------             -----
comp-esxi-01_vmhba2  10:00:00:90:fa:53:f4:60  {c832425d03f84644be37ae3d4e49186c, comp-esxi-01, 1}
comp-esxi-01_vmhba3  10:00:00:90:fa:53:f4:61  {c832425d03f84644be37ae3d4e49186c, comp-esxi-01, 2}
```

My problem is that I need $global:Xtrem_HBA_list to contain the value from name, port-address and the second value from ig-id (comp-esxi-01). I am having difficulty extracting the value from the array within the array.

Thanks to Matt! I updated my code and got the exact output I was looking for.

```
$global:Xtrem_HBA_list = @()
$global:arr_HBAs = @()
$global:Xtrem_HBA_list += (Get-XtremInitiators).name
foreach ($i in $global:Xtrem_HBA_list){
    $global:arr_HBAs += Get-XtremInitiator -InitiatorName $i | Select name,port-address,@{Name="ig-id";Expression={($_."ig-id")[1]}}
}
```

Comment: Will it _always_ be the second value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple basic ways to get this.

- A loop that extracts the value from the array at every pass.
- A loop that uses `Add-Member` to create another property that 'extracts' the information and use `Select` to pull that column.
- Using a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee692794.aspx) that will output the `ig-id` column but with only the second value from your array. This one is also easier as it will let us use the same name.

I'm opting for the latter suggestion. I am not using `write-host` on purpose here as it will just go to the output stream by default whereas `write-host` will just go to console

```
$global:Xtrem_HBA_list |  Select name,port-address,@{Name="ig-id";Expression={($_."ig-id")[1]}}
```

Note that if there is less than two elements a null will be returned. In that same scenario it could generate an error depending on your strict mode. Your mileage will vary but you can easily harden that with some if statements if need be.

Comment: Great idea using a calculated property! I forgot about those. `$global:Xtrem_HBA_list | % {[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$_.Name;PortAddress=$_."port-address";IGID=$_."ig-id"[1]}}`

Comment: @MadTomVane Only thing I have to say about that is it seems odd to make a whole new object when you only need to change/add the one property. Not sure if there a  performance trade off at some point.